# Are questions about brewing non-alcoholic on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask how to convert my spoiled wine to vinegar (follow-up on [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/can-i-water-plants-with-spoiled-wine) question). Is this on-topic here?

Comment: what about kefir, kombucha and other brewing organisms and beverages?

Answer (score 4):

Producing vinegar is fermentation of alcoholic beverages; it's just that it's away from alcohol to acetic acid.   A number of the principles that homebrewers adhere to would apply, and there are beer styles where an acetic flavor is acceptable.

I personally don't have a problem with it, but some of the other moderators may have a reasonable argument against it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I'll wait a couple of days more and if no one is against, I'll be becoming more active member of this community (HB.SE) :D

Comment: +1.  I think it's on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your question is off-topic.

You don't brew your spoiled wine to make vinegar. You just store it somewhere so that it turns into vinegar by itself.

If a question is about non-alcoholic beverages it's on-topic if it's about making a tea or coffee. (I'd say more generally, if the beverage is hot at least in one of the steps of making process)

From the [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brew_1) for brew:

> 1. [transitive, intransitive] brew something to make beer
>
> This beer is brewed in the Czech Republic.
>
> 2. [transitive] brew something to make a hot drink of tea or coffee
>
> freshly brewed coffee
>
> 3. [intransitive] (especially British English) (of tea or coffee) to be mixed with hot water and become ready to drink
>
> Always let tea brew for a few minutes.