# Can we stop accepting new answers for old questions after some time?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if it would be possible to stop accepting answers for questions that are very old, and already answered. This is a normal practice in other SEs I believe.

Why?

There a interesting questions that need focus and attention, and very, very old questions that already have acceptable answers that are getting completely unneeded attention. It seems we're in an odd cycle where we just recycle old posts over and over again.

Example:

[Questions like this](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/720/alternatives-to-a-hydrometer) (there are at least ten questions well over 3 years old this is just a random pick). **This question is over 10 years old** and still is getting activity. For some reason, the community bot, or *someone* touches these questions, which makes them active and bumps them to the top page and they get a bunch of unneeded activity. Raising up these dead (and honestly not very high quality) questions over and over and over isn't benefitting users, or the authors who probably stopped brewing two years after they asked the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Can we stop accepting new answers for old questions after some time?**

The simple answer is **no**.

The reason I would say no is due to the fact that once in awhile someone may show up on the site with an extraordinary answer to a particular subject matter. It would be a shame if such a possibility could not happen simply because a question was closed due to time placement ruling.

Comment: Can you give me an example? This problem is currently watering down this SE badly and the imagined edge case of "extraordinary answer to a particular subject matter" seems like a really poor reason to keep the quality low as a whole. There's nothing stopping anyone from asking a similar question and answering it as there are no duplicate questions closed here.

Comment: @rob Just because this site is so called dead, doesn't mean it's impossible a new user/old user have a good answer for an old unanswered/answered question.

Comment: @SnackExchange I'm not sure why this comment is on this question. Yes, that certainly is a real possibility. However, that possibility is not being reflected in reality. My idea is not a great solution, it's a shortcut to the lack of meaningful moderation here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm with Ken.

I have [answered](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/are-questions-about-brewing-non-alcoholic-on-topic-here/521#521) an 11-years-old question just about half an hour ago; and I think I've added more information than the old answer had done.

Also, you should consider this that new users always come to any sites.

Comment: My answer is related to the SO site itself- not the meta site. This answer doesn't remotely address that.

Comment: That said, do what you want, this SE site is effectively dead and this, nor other meta questions will likely ever be addressed.

Comment: What's the difference? On the main site also you can have an answer that is more complete than the old answer.

Comment: The difference is that it's a different site entirely and my question doesn't relate to it- it's simply irrelevant. It seems you've ignored my justifications in the body of text, and simply reacted to the title. Yes, in theory an answerer could come 10 years late and add a useful answer. In reality- the homebrew SE site is cannibalizing itself with circular updates on low quality questions and answers.

Comment: But as I said, do what you wish. There is no moderation here, so you will happily get your way and no meaningful changes will likely ever be made to improve quality or engagement.

Comment: So ask the moderators to improve the quality. Don't ask them to stop accepting new answers for old questions. New answers can be of high quality. What deserves to be stopped is the low quality things. Of course, low quality questions and answers aren't banned on SE. They are just down-voted.

Comment: This question was my attempt at asking moderators to improve quality by doing the bare minimum. This clearly isn't going to get enacted, and you're clearly going to get your way. I have no idea why you want to engage in this pedantic back and forth, but I simply have no further interest in doing so. Good luck here, and happy brewing.

Comment: I have edited my comment a little

Comment: BTW, please look at my first question on the main homebrewing site

Comment: This site is dead.  I came here every day for a year or two.  Now I haven't come here in many moons and here we are discussing how dead it is in here.  Vinegar, tea, sauerkraut... have at 'er.  With near-zero traffic, posting Q&A or other commentary in this forum has become meaningless.  All hail the Facebook.

Comment: @dmtaylor moons or months?

Comment: @SnackExchange Yes.  If you're not from USA, "moons" is slang for months.